# Spring Bean running in its own thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

Within my web application, I am trying to create a directory polling bean using Java SDK7 WatchService. What I would like to achieve is to run this bean in its own thread so that it does not block the application. Something like:

```
  <bean id="directoryPoller" class="org...MyDirectoryPoller" scope="thread"/>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am afraid you will have to create this thread manually with Spring:

```
<bean id="pollThread" class="java.lang.Thread" init-method="start" destroy-method="interrupt">
    <constructor-arg ref="watchServiceRunnableWrapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="watchServiceRunnableWrapper" class="WatchServiceRunnableWrapper">
    <constructor-arg ref="watchService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="WatchService" class="java.nio.file.WatchService" destroy-method="close"/>
```

The `WatchServiceRunnableWrapper` is simple:

```
public class WatchServiceRunnableWrapper implements Runnable {

    private WatchService WatchService;

    public WatchServiceRunnableWrapper(WatchService watchService) {
        this.watchService = watchService;
    }

    public void run() {
        watchService.poll();
        //
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it more-or-less should work and shutdown gracefully.

Comment: Well it is not really about the WatchService, it is really about creating a new thread - can you explain where the new thread in your example is created? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, okay, I can see it is done by implementing Runnable. Thanks, that is excatly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Java 7's WatchService, but you could use Springs' [scheduling support](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) for this. Here's [yet another tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-3-task-scheduling-via.html) and googling for something like Spring Scheduled probably finds loads more.